# Generic irreducibility of parabolic induction

Tags: rt.representation-theory, automorphic-forms, langlands-conjectures, p-adic-groups, induced-representations

In J.Bernstein's notes: REPRESENTATION OF P-ADIC GROUPS, he remarked the following result(see P.88):
Let $G$ be a reductive group defined over nonarchimedean local field $F$, $P$ parabolic subgroup of $G$ with Levi-decomposition $P=MN$, and $\rho$ be any irreducible smooth representation of $M$. Then $i_{G,M}(\psi \rho)$ is irreducible for generic unramified character $\psi$ of $M$.
I want to know the proof, but i haven't found a proof yet. Thanks so much for providing a proof or reference!

Comment: To improve your question, you should recall the notation : $G$ is a $p$-adic reductive group, $M$ a Levi subgroup, and so on ...

Answer (score 2):

You can find the answer of your question (and any other question of this kind) in the book of Renard "Représentations des groupes réductifs p-adiques" (http://www.math.polytechnique.fr/~renard/Padic.pdf Théorème p.295 of the file).

Comment: Yes, thanks! p.295 of the file is p.287 of D.Renard's book.

Answer (score 2):

See Theorem 6.6.1 in Casselman's notes titled "Introduction to the theory of admissible representations of $p$-adic groups", available from https://www.math.ubc.ca/~cass/research/pdf/p-adic-book.pdf

Comment: Thanks! This is the unitary case. J.Bernstein's beautiful argument had implied it. We want to know the general case.